# How to remove duplicate \n (line break) from a string and keep only one?

Tags: javascript, string, line-breaks

I have a string like this:

> This is a sentence.\n This is sentence 2.\n\n\n\n\n\n This is sentence 3.\n\n And here is the final sentence.

What I want to is:

> This is a sentence.\n This is sentence 2.\n This is sentence 3.\n And here is the final sentence.

I want to remove all duplicated \n characters from a string but keep only one left, is it possible to do like that in javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex as `/\n+/g` to [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) it with single `\n`

[image]

```js
const str =
  "This is a sentence.\n This is sentence 2.\n\n\n\n\n\n This is sentence 3.\n\n And here is the final sentence.";
const result = str.replace(/\n+/g, "\n");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Using `\n+` is sub optimal because it will also target single `\n`, which don't need to be replaced.

Comment: Probably better to use `\n{2,}` to avoid re-matching the single `\n` characters and replacing them with themselves.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for another approach. Added in brain cache

Answer (score 1):

You may try replacing `\n{2,}` with a single `\n`:

```js
var input = "This is a sentence.\n This is sentence 2.\n\n\n\n\n\n This is sentence 3.\n\n And here is the final sentence.";
var output = input.replace(/\n{2,}\s*/g, '\n');
console.log(output);
```